# Can the tooltip text on the tag scores be improved?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I hovered over the number, and it took me a few moments to realize what the tooltip was saying (still not sure I really understand it).  The wording could be better. I believe it was saying:

```
You answered x questions in this tag, and received total rep of y from those answers.
```

[image]

The non-wiki thing would be indecipherable to a newcomer. There's a lot of moving parts in the sentences. Score is ambiguous; is that upvotes or reputation? Hard to believe I've averaged less than two rep on each answer in the C# tag.

Comment: IMO, the only thing unclear is the total score thing. That being said, I agree it might be confusing to a new user.

Comment: @Jon: It's confusing to me, and I've been here awhile. But maybe I'm just dense.

Answer (score 1):

I am open to rephrasing this but there are a few fairly tricky rules in play.

Community Wiki answers are totally ignored when we assign out tag badges, additionally, tag badges are assigned based on score - that is - number of upvotes minus number of downvotes.

So, the scores we show on the user page, reflect those rules. That way you can tell you are one upvote away from a coveted bronze badge.

I don't really want to change any rules, but am totally open to a better phrasing for this sentence.

Comment: How about *You answered x questions in this tag, and received y qualified upvotes from those answers.* I'd be OK with the term "qualified" being described elsewhere. But "score" can mean anything.

Comment: For the questions, *x questions you asked in this tag received y qualified upvotes.*

Comment: then meta will be flooded with "what is a qualified upvote" :)

Comment: The biggest problem I have is with the word "score." I think if you replaced that with "net upvotes" it would be good enough.

Comment: "Score" is used in other places on the site and is pretty much accepted terminology; I'm not a big fan of making a new "qualified upvote" term just for this one tooltip

Comment: @Michael: Is "score" actually defined anywhere?  It's not in the [glossary](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-overflow-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms)

Comment: @Robert, surely you can add it :)

Comment: @waffles: I'm not convinced that "score" is a commonly-used, well-known term in the SE universe. Is it?

Comment: @Robert I don't know if it's "officially defined", but it's used to refer to the sum of up and downvotes anywhere that value is important (the tag "top users" pages come to mind)

Comment: @waffles: I added "score" to the glossary, and clarified the [faq] question describing all of the badges.

Answer (score 0):

The question number should be separated out and set before the answer number, then the tool-tips can be separate.